# Celery Worker exited prematurely: signal 9 (SIGKILL) on serializer.is_valid()

Tags: python, django, celery

I know that there are some questions already about this topic, so I understand the general idea, but this is more specific.
In some job that runs on our celery worker, we're creating a lot of objects (about 2000). 
Seems like every time, at some point, around the 2000th object (1700-1900) we get this error:
`Worker exited prematurely: signal 9 (SIGKILL)`
And it always seems to happen around this part of the code:

```
serializer = ModelSerializer(data=model_data)
Logger.info("serializer created")
if serializer.is_valid() is True:
    Logger.info("serializer valid")
```

I do see the first log, so I guess the serializer is created successfully, but I don't see the second log. And it's not that the serializer is not valid, because that case is covered as well. I just stop seeing any logs from the job after that line of code (`if serializer.is_valid()`). 
When trying to create less objects it seems fine.
So my question is why would using a lot of serializer.is_valid() in one celery job cause that process killing?

Exact errors:

```
Process 'ForkPoolWorker-3' pid:890 exited with 'signal 9 (SIGKILL)' 

Task handler raised error: WorkerLostError('Worker exited prematurely: signal 9 (SIGKILL).',)   

billiard.exceptions.WorkerLostError: Worker exited prematurely: signal 9 (SIGKILL).
```

Comment: Could you please paste the whole error from your log? If it contains some private information, please obfuscate it.

Comment: @DejanLekic added it. Thanks.

Comment: What does `is_valid()` do?

Comment: @DejanLekic that's how the serializer makes sure the data is valid before creating an object.